# Show that: $t_{n-1}+t_n=n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

How to can prove that : 
$$ t_{n-1}+t_n=n^2.$$
where $t_n$ is number of points with integers coordinates in a square isosceles triangle of side $n$:

- http://i45.tinypic.com/ndse9.jpg

Comment: You probably need the square to have one vertex at a point with integer coordinate and sides parallel to the axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the expression:

$$
t_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

This comes from summing the finite series

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k,
$$
The $k$ is the number of lattice points in each row of your triangle, and there are $n$ rows.

So,

$$
t_n+t_{n-1}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{(n-1)n}{2}=\frac{n^2+n+n^2-n}{2}=n^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Because the dots happen to be arranged in a $n\times n$  square.

Comment: This is a proof?